# Creating yaml list using the go template

Tags: go, go-templates

I am looking to create a yaml file in the following format. Using [Go template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template)

```
  Custom_listeners:
    Config1 : config_value
    Config2 : config_value    

    copy_files:
      - source_path: /path/to/file.txt
        destination_path: /tmp/file.txt
```

I am using the follow template code to get the value

```
Template : 
custom_listeners:  {{ range $cl := $.Vars.CustomListeners }}
    {{ range $k,$v := $cl.Values }}{{ $k }}: "{{ $v }}"
    {{ end }}{{ end }}
```

```
Custom listener map : 

type CustomListener map[string]interface{}
```

What changes can I made to above template to create the yaml in the follow format. with `-` on the  source_path:

```
 Custom_listeners: 
   copy_files:
     - source_path1: /path/to/file.txt
       destination_path: /tmp/file.txt

     - source_path2: /path/to/file.txt
       destination_path: /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: Any update on this please

Comment: Why you don't use a yaml package? https://go.dev/play/p/_GOS8Mxzs2j

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted?

```
tmpStr := `Custom_listeners:
    {{ range $Custom_listener:=$.Custom_listeners }}{{ range $k,$v:=$Custom_listener }}{{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
    {{ end }}{{ end }}
copy_files:
  - source_path: {{ $.source_path }}
  destination_path: {{ $.destination_path }}
`
    data := map[string]any{
        "Custom_listeners": []map[string]string{
            {"Config1": "config_value"},
            {"Config2": "config_value"},
        },
        "source_path":      "/path/to/file.txt",
        "destination_path": "/tmp/file.txt",
    }

    tmp := template.New("yaml template")
    tmp, _ = tmp.Parse(tmpStr)
    tmp.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
```

but why do`t use yaml package like... "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" ?